# "10387" using up battery

Tags: battery, battery-life, apk, processes, unknown-sources

I have absolutely no clue what this process is. I've never seen it before, and I check the battery usage tab a lot. I'm worried it's a virus or something, although I do have CM Security installed, I download lots of APK files. My phone has been slower than ever all day today, so it is quite concerning.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the process information. I opened it via battery usage statistics in settings.]
<sup>screenshot of the process information (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: If the app has no name, its UID is shown here. You can find out the package name from the command line, e.g. using `adb shell "dumpsys package" >package.dmp`, and then search that dump file for a line assigning that number to a "userId".

Comment: Still, if I may, uninstall CMS. It does little more than bother you with pop-ups and spam.